# Column Computation in Grails Search Criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I would like to to know how to perform a column computation using a grails criteria. Basically the criteria syntax that will translate to the following sql query.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (first_column * second_column) > 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use [sql restrictions](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String%29):

```
def results = DomainClass.withCriteria {
  ...
  sqlRestriction "(first_column * second_column) > 30"
}
```